# How to fill a transparent image with a progress bar ? #CSS #HTML #Jquery?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, fill

I'm trying to fill a glass of beer at 30% with html and CSS with the technique of this progress bar [csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/).
But I don't know if it's possible.

I have an image of the glass of beer with transparency content (png in illustrator).
Do you know if it's possible to have the progress bar in background ? 
My tests were fruitless.:-(

Or do I have to use another technique ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Nicolas

Comment: Easily.. just try something. Tip: position: absolute; z-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go :D (this is what you can do with a few alterations to the css-trick example):
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/djnBD/

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fillable Beer Bottle</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".liquid").each(function() {
                $(this)
                    .data("origHeight", $(this).height())
                    .height(0)
                    .animate({
                        height: $(this).data("origHeight")
                    }, 1200);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .glass { 
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
            background-image: url('http://i40.tinypic.com/11hyr1j.png'); /* Beer Glass */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        .liquid {
            z-index:-1;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            width: 200px;
            background-image: url('http://i44.tinypic.com/f0vxbt.jpg'); /* Beer Liquid Pattern */
            /* Remove the bottom two lines to stop animation */
            -webkit-animation: move 150s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: move 150s linear infinite;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes move {
            0% {
               background-position: 0 0;
            }
            100% {
               background-position: 2212px 0px;
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes move {
            0% {
               background-position: 0 0;
            }
            100% {
               background-position: 2212px 0px;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="glass">
            <span class="liquid" style="height: 30%"></span>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to launch this animation only on mouse:over ?

Comment: Many thanks Mohammad ! It works well on your example on jsfiddle ! But I have tried to put this code in an html page on my computer and it doesn't work... Mouseenter don't launch the background... :-( I don't see why because I've just copied et paste your code. Aaarrgggh I've no more hairs and nails ;-)  Here is the example on-line : http://eclairagepublic.net/coulisses/demo-datawall/beer-example.html

Comment: It works ! You're the king of the web :-) Thank you so much for your help ! May the Saints of the web bless you ;-) Where are you from ?